# write on csv but getting empty file with no row and columns

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to use a CSV file to store some data.  This code creates the file:

```
with open('keras_character_W.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
    fieldnames = ['images', 'result_character']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
```

later, when I am read to store the variables, a command 's' stores them:

```
state = cv2.waitKey(0)
if state == ord('q'):
   break

elif state == ord('s'):
     writer.writerow({'images': '  '})
     writer.writerow({'images': 'guess_right = ', 'result_character': x, })
     writer.writerow({'images': 'final  = ', 'result_character': y , })
```

but the CSV file is empty.

"I checked the caps and if the condition  satisfied but didn't find anything the file even open on text editor not excel program "

Comment: `state` is user input? It’s difficult to understand what’s going, please include all relevant code and data. See: [mcve].

Comment: the state is an input from user keyboard obtained by clicking key and if the key was 's' then it will save

Comment: You shouldn’t be using `ord()` for that, if the input is `”s”`.

Comment: the result of the cv2.waitKey(0) is not s i need to use ord to convert it to be matching the letter ord

Comment: Aaah, it wasn’t clear in your post that the input isn’t coming from stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear from your example, but I think you are closing the CSV early.

When you do `with open('keras_character_W.csv', 'w') as csvFile:`, you start a context in which:

- The previous contents of `keras_character_W.csv` are erased
- The file is open for writing
- The file will be closed when you exit the `with` statement, meaning you stop indenting.

Hope this helps!

Keep hacking!  Keep notes.